# Hiding / clearing Stage3D on iOS hides 2D screen content - how can I get it to render 2D again?

Tags: ios, air, stage3d, away3d

After using and then switching back from Stage3D, is there a way to require AIR on iOS to recognize that the 2D stage is not empty and start displaying 2D again?

My team's app has run well on Android and the ADL emulator, but on iOS (iPad 12.1.4 latest), I get a blank screen (which I tested and is the 'empty' stage).  The point at which this happens is after I try to hide/disable/change visibility on my Stage3D content (Away3D) to go to a 2D menu.  It isn't crashing, because I can still interact with the invisible menus and return to the stage3D scene which displays perfectly again.  If I do not remove the stage3D layer, the rest of the scene displays correctly as well.  I have tried all sorts of searches and ideas, but cannot seem to figure this one out myself. I am using Adobe Animate, and AIR release 32.0.0.89.  I have not updated Animate to the latest version since I am mid-project.